# Add tooltip to font awesome icon

Tags: icons, tooltip, font-awesome

Has anyone here added tooltips to font-awesome icons?

I have the [following jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HarrietFiddles/1btr64kw/1/), but cannot seem to find a guide to add tooltips to the icons.

```
<header>
  <!-- icons for settings, change pwd and list of active sessions -->
  <div id="menuIcons">
    <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
  </div>

  <!-- display welcome text -->
  <div id="welcomeText">
    <p>Welcome Harriet</p>
  </div>

</header>
```

Comment: OK, so I guess there is a new feature that requires code to be submitted along with the jsfiddle. I am having trouble doing just that, that is why it is showing up all funny above. If any of you have some ideas re the original post, I would appreciate advice.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

The issue of adding tooltips to any HTML-Output (not only FontAwesome) is an entire book on its own. ;-)

The default way would be to use the title-attribute:

```
  <div id="welcomeText" title="So nice to see you!">
    <p>Welcome Harriet</p>
  </div>
```

or

```
<i class="fa fa-cog" title="Do you like my fa-cog icon?"></i>
```

But since most people (including me) do not like the standard-tooltips, there are MANY tools out there which will "beautify" them and offer all sort of enhancements. My personal favourites are [jBox](http://stephanwagner.me/jBox/) and [qtip2](http://qtip2.com).

Comment: But this is not working in IE 11  is there any solution for it

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn985836%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Turn_on_and_use_the_Blocking_untrusted_fonts_feature

Comment: I ahve used data-toggle=tooltip its working but creating tooltip twice in chrome

Comment: That's a different issue then. I'd suggest to post a dedicated question for it.

Comment: it's not working

Answer (score 21):

Simply use title in tag like

```
<i class="fa fa-edit" title="Edit Mode"></i>
```

This will show 'Edit Mode' when hover that icon.

Comment: This could help: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn985836%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Turn_on_and_use_the_Blocking_untrusted_fonts_feature

Answer (score 8):

You should use 'title' attribute along with 'data-toogle' (bootstrap).

For example

```
<i class="fa fa-info" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!"></i>Hover over me
```

and do not forget to add the javascript to display the tooltip

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This shows both the tooltip - and the `title` as the browser would render it. Therefore you end up with it saying "Hooray!" in 2 different places which looks very odd.

Answer (score 5):

In regards to this question, this can be easily achieved using a few lines of SASS;

HTML:

```
<a href="https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=techninja" data-tool-tip="What's a tech ninja?" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-2x fa-user-ninja" id="tech--ninja"></i></a>
```

CSS output would be:

```
a[data-tool-tip]{
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
}

a[data-tool-tip]::after{
    content: attr(data-tool-tip);
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: dimgrey;
    padding: 1em 3em;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: .5em;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -180%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: 
    transform ease-out 150ms,
    bottom ease-out 150ms;
}

a[data-tool-tip]:hover::after{
    transform: scale(1);
    bottom: 200%;
}
```

Basically the attribute selector [data-tool-tip] selects the content of whatever's inside and allows you to animate it however you want.

Comment: This is a great alternative for `title`, because it can be styled. I personally avoid adding more modules to do something as simple as a tool-tip.

Answer (score 2):

[codepen](https://codepen.io/jonmilner/pen/bfkKF) Is perhaps a helpful example.

```
<div class="social-icons">
  <a class="social-icon social-icon--codepen">
    <i class="fa fa-codepen"></i>
    <div class="tooltip">Codepen</div>
</div>

body {  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

/* Color Variables */
$color-codepen: #000;

/* Social Icon Mixin */
@mixin social-icon($color) {
  background: $color;
  background: linear-gradient(tint($color, 5%), shade($color, 5%));
  border-bottom: 1px solid shade($color, 20%);
  color: tint($color, 50%);

  &:hover {
    color: tint($color, 80%);
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px shade($color, 20%);
  }

  .tooltip {
    background: $color;
    background: linear-gradient(tint($color, 15%), $color);
    color: tint($color, 80%);

    &:after {
      border-top-color: $color;
    }
  }
}

/* Social Icons */
.social-icons {
  display: flex;
}

.social-icon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: all 0.15s ease;

  &:hover {
    color: #fff;

    .tooltip {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translate(-50%, -150%);
    }
  }

  &:active {
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
  }

  &--codepen { @include social-icon($color-codepen); }

  i {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
  }
}

/* Tooltips */
.tooltip {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 0.8rem 1rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  z-index: 1;

  &:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    content: "";
    border: solid;
    border-width: 10px 10px 0 10px;
    border-color: transparent;
    transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I have found is to wrap your Font Awesome Icon in an `<a></a>` tag:

```
   <Tooltip title="Node.js" >
     <a>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faNode} size="2x" />
     </a>
   </Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **title** attribute

```
<i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true" title="Print"
   style="font-size: 45px;cursor: pointer;" >
</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply with native html & css :

```
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>

/* Tooltip container */
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black; /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
}

/* Tooltip text */
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;

  /* Position the tooltip text */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;

  /* Fade in tooltip */
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

/* Tooltip arrow */
.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Here is the source of the [example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp) from w3schools