# How to show text on mouse over in ag-grid cellRendererParams actions

Tags: angular, ag-grid

[Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNSqQ.png).I want to show some text on mouse hover for each icon in ag-grid. here my code. In the Action column, I am getting the result as three icons. Mouseover on each icon I want to show the type of icon.

```
{
  headerName: 'Actions',
  sortable: false,
  cellRenderer: 'buttonRenderer',
  cellRendererParams: {
    actions: [
      {
        onClick: this.onViewActionClick.bind(this),
        label: 'Input File',
        icon: 'input',
        color: 'primary',
        show: this.showAction.bind(this),
      },
      {
        onClick: this.onEditActionClick.bind(this),
        label: 'Error File',
        icon: 'error',
        color: 'error',
        show: this.showAction.bind(this),
      },
      {
        onClick: this.onEditActionClick.bind(this),
        label: 'Log File',
        icon: 'view_headline',
        color: 'warn',
        show: this.showAction.bind(this),
      },
    ],
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you asked (it doesn't involve the renderer), but the grid already provides tooltips via the column definition's 'tooltip' property, which is a callback that provides the text.

See the documentation at https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-properties/

Comment: Thanks for responding. tooltip is working on the column definition. But I want to show text on column result data. I have three button icons as a result of the action column. So on each button mouse over I want to show the type of button.

Comment: Attached the image.

Comment: In that case, you can just add a 'title' attribute to each of the buttons in your renderer, e.g. 
`<button title="Info" (click)="onInfo()"> or you can use one of the several other ways of generating tooltips, such as Bootstrap, Material Design, etc.

Comment: It's not working. Here buttons mean icons as shown in the attached image.

Comment: When I said "or you can use one of the several other ways of generating tooltips, such as Bootstrap, Material Design, etc.", I was anticipating that your icons might not actually be buttons.  The point is that there shouldn't be anything special about creating your tooltip related to the fact that this is a renderer. What works elsewhere should work here too. See for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34807000/add-tooltip-to-font-awesome-icon

Comment: yeah it is working elsewhere, but not sure why it's not working in the above code.

Comment: the title is working. we are using a custom button type for action row.